# C - how to use extern variable

Tags: c, extern

I am learning how to use a extern variable, I wrote a simple program to try it but it doesnt seem to be working. I've looked at some examples but I don't know whats wrong.

Here is my code:

#### globals.h

```
#ifndef GLOBALS_H_
#define GLOBALS_H_

extern int gval;

#endif /* GLOBALS_H_ */
```

#### main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "globals.h"

int main() {
int gval = 4;
printf("1st value is: %i", gval);

printf("2nd value is: %i", modded());
}
```

#### modify.c

```
#include "globals.h"

int modded() {
return gval++;
}
```

The error seems to be that `gval` is undefined in `modify.c`, but I don't get how.

Comment: Here is a great related question describing how to use extern variables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-share-a-variable-between-source-files-in-c-with-extern-but-how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your main.c to

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "globals.h"

int gval; // define (allocate space for) the global variable

int main(void) {
    // int gval = 4; -- wrong -- this defines and initializes a local variable that hides the global of the same name
    gval = 4; // use the global variable, assigning to it ... or you could initialize it at the definition above and omit this line
    printf("1st value is: %i", gval);

    printf("2nd value is: %i", modded());
}
```

and change `modded` to

```
int modded(void) {
    // return gval++; -- wrong -- this is postfix increment and returns the value *before* incrementing
    return ++gval; // use prefix increment
}
```

You also should have a modify.h that contains the prototype for `modded` that you include in main.c, or just put `modded` inside main.c before `main`.

Another approach is to change `modded` to not return a value, since it is changing a global, thus:

```
void modgval(void) {
    ++gval; // or gval++
}
```

And then in main:

```
    printf("1st value is: %i", gval);
    modgval();
    printf("2nd value is: %i", gval);
```

Answer (score 3):

As it stands, you've declared a global variable `gval` in the header, and you've hidden that global declaration with a locally defined variable `gval` in the `main()` function.  This is legal, but only sometimes (I'm tempted to say 'occasionally' or 'seldom') what is intended.  If you use GCC, using the `-Wshadow` option would warn you about shadowing variables like that.  It is generally a bad idea to shadow global variables.

The simplest fix to your code is to move the definition of `gval` outside `main()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "globals.h"

int gval = 4;

int main(void)
{
    printf("1st value is: %i", gval);
    printf("2nd value is: %i", modded());
    return 0;
}
```

However, you should note that although it will compile and run, the second value printed will be the same as the first because `modded()` returns the unmodified version of the value.  To see the effect, you need:

```
#include "globals.h"

int modded(void)
{
    return ++gval;
}
```

Were it my code, there'd be a declaration of `modded()` in `globals.h`.  You should not be calling a function without a prototype in scope according to C99 and C11 (the old and current C standard).  Of necessity, the original C89 standard was more lax about that rule; it had to be to accommodate the pre-existing non-standard code.  However, for code written in the 21st Century, there's no real excuse for not having a prototype in scope before you use a function.

Answer (score 2):

A global extern variable must be defined somewhere, but in your code, the `gval` in `main` is a local variable, there's no definition of the global variable. This line

```
extern int gval;
```

is a **declaration**, not a **definition**. In other words, you must have

```
int gval;
```

somewhere outside all functions.

Even if a global `gval` were defined, note that the global `gval` is invisible in the scope of local `gval`

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example describing how to share a variable between source files:

```
File 1:

  int GlobalVariable;         // explicit definition, this actually allocates as well as describing
  void SomeFunction(void);        // function prototype (declaration), assumes defined elsewhere, normally from include file.

  int main() {
    GlobalVariable = 1;
    SomeFunction();
    return 0;
  }

File 2:

  extern int GlobalVariable;  // implicit declaration, this only describes and assumes allocated elsewhere, normally from include

  void SomeFunction(void) {       // function header (definition)
    ++GlobalVariable;
  }
```

In this example, the variable GlobalVariable is defined in File 1. In order to utilize the same variable in File 2, it must be declared. Regardless of the number of files, a global variable is only defined once, however, it must be declared in any file outside of the one containing the definition.

In your case **gval** in main is a local variable, instead define a global variable and then use extern to share variable in different source files.

Answer (score 0):

Just put Gval before the main declaration and you're ready to go ;)